# I try to execute into container with exec_run but doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, dockerpy

I try to execute 4 commands into a container (it has a mysql database) but if i do it in anothe terminal work, but if a create a container and then execute the commands, it not working. I have this code:
this code create the container but dont execute the command 1 ,2 , 3 and 4.

```
import docker
from docker.types import Mount
from threading import Thread

client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')

container= client.containers.run(
 "python_base_image:v02",
 detach=True,
 name='201802750001M04',
 ports={'3306/tcp': None, '80/tcp': None},
 mounts= 
  [Mount("/var/lib/mysql","201802750001M04_backup_db",type='volume')]
)

command1 = "sed -i '/bind/s/^/#/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf"
command2 = "mysql --user="root" --password="temprootpass" -- 
execute="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'macripco'@'172.17.0.1' 
IDENTIFIED BY '12345';""
command3 = "mysql --user="root" --password="temprootpass" -- 
execute="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'macripco'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY '12345';""
command4 = "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart"

a = container.exec_run(command1,detach=False,stream=True,stderr=True, 
 stdout=True)
b = container.exec_run(command2,detach=False,stream=True,stderr=True, 
 stdout=True)
c = container.exec_run(command3,detach=False,stream=True,stderr=True, 
 stdout=True)
d = container.exec_run(command4,detach=False,stream=True,stderr=True, 
 stdout=True)`
```

But if i execute the commands later(in another terminal), once the container has been created, that work. I need create and execute the commands together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That was a problem about time execution, that was resolved with time.sleep(10) between two executions, after create container and before exec_run